# How to change the placeholder text upon clicking the option value in datalist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I tried to change the value upon clicking the option in the datalist the values are not changing in the placeholder. When I choose "Farmer" am getting "Farmer", but I need to get "Search Farmer Here..." and so on.

```
<input type="text1" list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser" placeholder="Search Here..">
<datalist id="browsers" style="font-size:20pt;">
  <option value="Farmer">
  <option value="Input products">
  <option value="Output products">
  <option value="Customers">
  <option value="Suppliers">
  <option value="Sales Invoices">
  <option value="Purchase Bills">
  <option value="Payments">
  <option value="collections">
</datalist>
```

I tried by passing id like below

```
$("#yourtextboxid").attr("placeholder", "variable");
```

also I tried

```
document.getElementsByName('Email')[0].placeholder='new text for email';
```

but still am not getting required results. Did I missed any syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the input that calls a function to replace both the value, and the placeholder text.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#browser');
input.addEventListener('change', handleInput, false);

function handleInput(e) {
  const { value, placeholder } = e.target;
  e.target.placeholder = `Search ${value} here`;
  e.target.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser" placeholder="Search Here..">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Farmer">
  <option value="Input products">
  <option value="Output products">
  <option value="Customers">
  <option value="Suppliers">
  <option value="Sales Invoices">
  <option value="Purchase Bills">
  <option value="Payments">
  <option value="collections">
</datalist>
```

Comment: @Andy...it is working...Thanks but I can type only a single letter only...but I need to search more than one letters...

Comment: Does that work better for you? Type the characters but make sure you hit Enter at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS solution below. You can add an event listener to your first `input` and listen to the `change` event. Inside the callback, you can change the placeholder value to the datalist value:

```js
let firstInput = document.querySelector('#first')
let secondInput = document.querySelector('#second')

firstInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  secondInput.disabled = e.target.value === ''
  secondInput.placeholder = `Search ${e.target.value.toLowerCase()}`
});
```

```css
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: .5rem auto;
  padding: .5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" list="firstList" name="first" id="first" placeholder="Search here...">
<datalist id="firstList">
  <option value="Farmer">
  <option value="Input products">
  <option value="Output products">
  <option value="Customers">
  <option value="Suppliers">
  <option value="Sales Invoices">
  <option value="Purchase Bills">
  <option value="Payments">
  <option value="collections">
</datalist>

<input type="text" list="secondList" name="second" id="second" placeholder="Search here..." disabled>
<datalist id="secondList">
  <option value="Item #1">
  <option value="Item #2">
  <option value="Item #3">
  <option value="Item #4">
  <option value="Item #5">
</datalist>
```