# Placeholder text is not displaying after selecting the values in datalist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tried to change the placeholder text upon selecting the values from datalist. The values got changed but when I tried to enter some text in the placeholder it is not allowing me to enter more that a letter. My code is below.

```
<input type="text" list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser" placeholder="Search Here..">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Datas">
  <option value="World">
  <option value="Static">  
</datalist>
```

Respective JS code is

```
const input = document.querySelector('#browser');
input.addEventListener('input', handleInput, false);

function handleInput(e) {
  const { value, placeholder } = e.target;
  e.target.placeholder = `Search ${value} here`;
  e.target.value = '';
}
```

Actually above code is partially working fine. When I click "Datas" am getting "search Datas here" message in the placeholder box. But it allows to enter a single letter only. I try to get values like, after selecting the values from datalist, the placeholder will show "Search Datas Here" and this will work like normal placeholder and it allows to enter more letters for search purposes.

Comment: You reset `e.target.value = ''` on every keystroke. That's why I didn't understand why you accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599671/6126373)

Comment: I tried to comment the code but am unable to enter more then a letter...how to reset on every key stroke.. Yes, But I tried only the dropdown option only but I totally forgot to check by typing text in placehoder...is there still any possibility...

Comment: I think, you need to explain better what you want to achieve with this. You can't have a value in an input field and still show the placeholder. That's why I used two different fields in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599673/6126373). So first, please, try to explain how it should work.

Comment: First When I select values from datalist, the place holder will show as "search <option value> here.." and after that when I click the placeholder textbox it will behave as normal placeholder .. and allow to enter more characters...hope it helps you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test if the value is equal to any option from the list before to perform your actions (change placeholder and clear input value)

Note options tag must be closed
`<option></option>`

```js
function onInput() {
    var browser= document.getElementById("browser")
    var opts = document.getElementById('browsers').childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
      if (opts[i].value === browser.value) {
        browser.placeholder = `Search ${opts[i].value} here`;
        browser.value = '';
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" list="browsers" oninput='onInput()'id="browser" placeholder="Search Here..">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Datas"></option>
  <option value="World"></option>
  <option value="Static"></option>
</datalist>
```